# Converting a class with java.lang.Object into Uni Mutiny returns null in API

Tags: java, api, object, quarkus, mutiny

I have a quarkus app that has a POST api returning a Uni .
The structure of Test class

```
class Test {
  String name;
  Object data;
}
```

I am passing the below as data from backend as response

```
{
    "data": {
        "value1": [
            {
              "type" : "String",
              "name" : "firstName"
            }
        ]
    },
    "name": "SUCCESS"
}
```

But what i get as response in the postman is ,

```
{
    "data": {
        "value1": [
            {}
        ]
    },
    "name": "SUCCESS"
}
```

Any idea why this happening. I am deploying the quarkus app in my local docker after taking a native build.
Using java 17 in the native package command

EDIT:
The api created is as follows

```
@Path("/getData")
@POST 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Uni<Test> getDataValue() { 
  Test newTest = new Test(); //populate test values return 
  return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> newTest) 
}
```

As mentioned by @Clement in the comments, it appears only in case of Native docker build. Works fine in case of JVM build

Comment: What does your REST API look like?

Comment: @geoand 
`
@Path("/getData")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Uni<Test> getDataValue() {
    Test newTest = new Test();
    //populate test values
   return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> newTest)

}

This is my rest api.

Comment: Does it work in JVM mode (dev mode for example)? It looks to me that the fields have been removed during the native compilation.

Comment: @clement Yes, it does work in the dev mode. Is there anyway to overcome that

Comment: @codeforHarman please add the code from the comment to the question itself as it's very hard to read in a comment

Comment: I'm wondering why it does not get registered automatically. Anyway, you can use the @RegisterForReflection annotation on the `Test` class.

Comment: A few more questions: are you using resteasy classic or resteasy reactive? I think we handle the automatic registration with resteasy reactive, but I can't remember with resteasy classic.

Comment: Used resteasy reactive. Still got the issue